# How to put a new column after a "sort" in a google sheets doc?

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following issue:
I create a column by pulling data from columns of dfferent sheets to ctreate a single column created from the unique values.

I the use that column via a transpose(sort(range)) to create column headings on a third sheet.

My problem is how can I then add a "Total" column without knowing how many columns there are going to be?  Its easy enough via an "IF" statement to check what columns there are and to build the queries, its just how to add the last column that has me stumped.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way for me to do this is create a custom function though google script and then use it as a formula. You can use the following script

```
//Do Not Edit This    
function ADDTOTAL(range) {
      return range+",Total";
    }
```

And then in your sheet type with your range

```
=SPLIT(ADDTOTAL(SORT('REPORT LOOKUP'!F:F)),",")
```

You don't even need to transpose in this case

Comment: I've never used google script before and I seem to be getting an error when I try this.  The code I am entering is:  function ADDTOTAL('REPORT LOOKUP'!F:F) {
  return range+",Total";
}      but it tells me I am missing a parameter.  What do I need to add?  Thanks

Comment: Oh, copy the script part as it is without editing. you type in your range only in the spreadsheet. Also you do not need to run the script. After pasting it, save and close script editor. Then just type in the formula in your sheet and it will work. I have edited my answer including your range where it needs to be set.